# Is there a way to customize ng-step?

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I've been trying to use stepper in ng-zorro but faced some styling limitations. ng-step is basically a combination of a few divs when I inspect an ng_step, the HTML shows the following:

```
<div class="ant-steps-item-tail ng-star-inserted">...</div>
<div class="ant-steps-item-icon">...</div>
<div class="ant-steps-item-content>...</div>
```

what I need is something like:

```
<div class="ant-steps-item-tail ng-star-inserted">...</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="ant-steps-item-icon">...</div>
<div class="ant-steps-item-content>...</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to insert this  into it.

Sorry for not explaining it properly, This is the best way I could put it.
If you still couldn't understand the question, you could inspect an ng-step, that might help clear out the question I have here.